# Protractor browser.pause() doesn't keep browser open?

Tags: protractor

I'm having a strange issue where when using a `browser.pause()` the debugger starts but the browser page will close after about 30-35 seconds. It makes it impossible to debug and look at things because I simply don't have enough time.

I assume there is a incorrect configuration somewhere, but I don't know where. I tried Googling but I didn't come up with anything that helped resolve the issue. It used to work perfectly fine.

Does anyone know where in the configuration I might need to look in order to fix it?

The protractor version I'm running is v2.5.1.

Comment: Could you please post your Protractor config? Also, why 2.5.1 - it is very old..Protractor 4 is currently stable..?

Comment: @alecxe Do I just need the file local.js? `protractor local.js --suite=blah`? And I can't quite answer your question about the protractor version. I don't always get pulled into testing but from what I'm aware of, upgrading causes problems.

Comment: Yup, please post that `local.js`, thanks.

Comment: @alecxe since the file is super long I decided to upload it [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/FRWfubaCqZjak78HMUnqbn) if you'd like me to add it in the question body, I can do so. I also removed the test suite names just to reduce the amount of lines to scroll through.

Comment: I also agree, Protractor is very old and might not work with the browser drivers and browser version. I would see if you could get a sample test with browser.pause working on the latest.

Comment: your config looks over good :P

Comment: @cnishina I updated to the latest version `v4.0.11` and I'm still having the same issue. I had a co-worker try to use a browser.pause() and his windows closed after 30 seconds too.